# How to get nested child handle and setting their values using WinApi

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I am trying to set  the text and listbox selected value of the following two handles:

1)  From First image below: handle name "Select Database File" parent - Edit, textbox and set it's property. I am able to get the parent handle but unable to get child Edit(textbox) and set it text's property.

```
//Getting Parent Handle
IntPtr hwnd = (IntPtr)Win32.Functions.FindWindow(null, "Select Database File");

//Attempting to get child handle
IntPtr h =
        (IntPtr)Win32.Functions.FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
    if (h != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        //setting text
                Win32.Functions.SetWindowText((IntPtr)h, "qwerty");
    }
```

Following Is a recursive function where I pass the Parent handle but this returns handle values instead of window/class name where I can edit/cast the child handle I need.
         public static List GetAllChildrenWindowHandles(IntPtr hParent,
      int maxCount)
            {

```
            List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
            int ct = 0;
            IntPtr prevChild = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr currChild = IntPtr.Zero;
            while (true && ct < maxCount)
            {
                currChild = (IntPtr)Win32.Functions.FindWindowEx(hParent, prevChild, null, null);
                if (currChild == IntPtr.Zero) break;
                result.Add(currChild);
                prevChild = currChild;
                ++ct;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

[image: Image 1 - Textbox]

2) From the second image  I need to get a list box (000DD04A4) from parent handle (00300762) and select the first item within the listbox,

[image: Image 2]

Comment: `FindWindowEx` is not recursive. The Edit control is a child of a ComboBox control which is a child of a ComboBoxEx32 control which is a child of the parent dialog. You need to search for them all in turn.

Comment: Added a recursive function to search for all child handles with the parent one of "Select Database File" but that returns me a list of handle numbers. Each time the application runs handle numbers they would be different. How would I Identify the child that I need to traverse into.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview). If nothing else, it provides you with richer information to identify specific UI interaction points.

Comment: You can use [`GetWindowText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta) to get window title from its handle.